# Does the Nikon 50mm 1.8G have a rubber seal?

Tags: lens, nikon, nikon-d7000

I have the 1.8D already and I know it doesn't have a seal. I am wondering of the G does because if so I might replace the D with a G so I can be better assured if I take my camera on holiday snowboarding that the water won't get in.

Comment: The assumption here is that you are wondering about the rubber seal around the mount. It is of course possible to have rubber seals on a lens in other locations such as the buttons as well. If you could clarify which seal you are interested in that would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both the 1.8G and 1.4G lenses have a rubber seal on the mount.

You can see it on Ken Rockwell's [review](http://kenrockwell.com/nikon/50mm-f18-g.htm#mex).  It is the raised, thin black strip just outside the metal mount.